# How to carry over form inputs to the next record in MS Access without using VBA

Tags: database, ms-access

I am using Access 2010 to build a database. The database is updated regularly by an intern so I am trying to make it as simple and user friendly as possible. I have created a form for entering records.

These records are based on minute by minute information so much of the information - like date, name, category, etc - is the same for multiple records. Therefore, I want these broader fields' contents to carry over when I reset the form for the next entry.

This is probably a common question and I have researched many forums, but non provide guidance on how this can be done without the use of any macro or VBA. Can this be done without it? If so, how?

Comment: Curious why no VBA?  That would seem the fastest way to accomplish this.  At least to me.

Comment: This is for another team in my department. Eventually they will be handling the database and neither of them are well versed with coding of any form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use VBA.  It's real simple though:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
   ' Add a line for each control that is to "remember" the last value entered
   ' and use that for the default value of the next new record created
   Me.[MyControlName].DefaultValue = Me.[MyControlName]

End Sub
```