# MS Access Data Entry-Don't change until i do the changes

Tags: vba, ms-access

iam working on a school monthly returns database, in which i enter data that comes in every month. during entries on the form, i want the month to remain the same until and unless i do the changes. the same thing i want for the name of the school.
can someone kindly assist with this?

Comment: You need to suspend the form's auto-update and handle it manually. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146658/ms-access-pop-up-and-modal-form-insert-record-without-save-button/48146946#48146946

Comment: @KostasK., don't think that's what OP is asking for. Suggest setting control's DefaultValue property. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841120/how-to-carry-over-form-inputs-to-the-next-record-in-ms-access-without-using-vba